# Does my smartphone need NFC to pay at car charging stations in Germany and The Netherlands?

Tags: automobiles, payment, electric-vehicle

I am renting an electric car for a longer trip and figuring out how to pay for (fast) charging stations in Germany and The Netherlands.  As of 2022, most charging stations do not yet allow paying for with a regular bank card ([this will change from 2023](https://www.autobild.de/artikel/e-autos-laden-an-ladestation-karte-bezahlen-ladekarte-rfid-17419097.html)), and dedicated cards or smartphone apps are still needed.  The charging card uses a Radio-frequency identification (RFID) chip (contactless), but how is this for the smartphone apps?  Can I scan a Quick Response (QR) code or does it need to support Near Field Communication (NFC)?

My smartphone does not support NFC, and I'm trying to understand if I need to order cards from the (largest) roaming providers (those cards cost money), or if I can count on my smartphone for paying at (fast) charging stations.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Germany, but for The Netherlands I found a few sources stating that you can pay via a QR-code and an app:

- [FastNed](https://support.fastned.nl/hc/nl/articles/205419217-Hoe-kan-ik-mijn-elektrische-auto-opladen-bij-Fastned-): How can I charge my EV at FastNed:

  - > When you start a charging session with a QR-code, you don't need a dedicated charging card or any other form of registration [...] **Scan the QR-code [...] choose the payment method in the app** [...]
- [Shell Recharge](https://www.shell.nl/consumenten/recharge.html):

  - > Ease of payment: use your Shell Recharge charge card, a card of another provider or **pay via a QR-code with your phone**
- [Mountoux.com](https://www.mountox.com/apps-voor-laden.html): Best charging station apps:

  - > Smoov App: [...] **Start charging session with QR-code, no need for a charging card, pay in the App (with your bank account, creditcard, [...])**

Note that I don't have firsthand experience in charging an EV and that it appears to strongly depend on which charging station / app combination you encounter.

Comment: At least Shell Recharge appears to be big in Germany too, so that gives me some confidence that it should work.